# Given a form, how do I find the fields present in them?

Tags: 7, forms

How do I get the list of fields present in a certain form, I know the form id, I just need the names of the fields present in that form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your template "template.php for example" or your module, and use

hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  var_dump($form);exit();
}

and you will get very detailed look at your form

Comment: That would also give me other things like `actions`, `submit` etc. But I just need the field names.

Comment: try dumping the other variables "form_state" and "form_id" usually they have them.